# vnc session show gray screen on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I'm trying to install VNC server on Ubuntu 14 LTS.
I installed the "vnc4server" package and started vncserver simply by:
"vncserver" command line.
(like: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14.04)

i got the session and i am trying to connect to that via my vnc viewer but i see gray empty screen.
how can i configure it in order to show normal desktop in the session?

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue, first of all, check if you have any Desktop Environment (eg, Unity, Gnome, KDE, xfce, lxde etc) installed on your system. You may use: echo $DESKTOP_SESSION or you can verify from env.

In my case, I have installed LXDE on Ubuntu server. It is important now to find the exact executable path of lxde, which is `/usr/bin/startlxde` in my case.

Replace the content of your `~/.vnc/xstartup` and paste following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/usr/bin/startlxde
```

Note: Above code is only valid for lxde.

[Source](http://rootcss.blogspot.com/2015/10/fixing-blankgrey-screen-with-three.html) (I have written a related post on my blog)